# Video playback issues in fedora 20

Tags: video, gstreamer, fedora, vlc, mplayer

last night I have installed fedora release 20. but I am not able to playback any videos. If I play a video file in, say VLC. the audio is alright. only the video is not being played.

No picture only sound.

I have tried installing,
vlc
smplayer
all gstreamer packages.

none seems to be working. I guess no issues related to graphics card. because all players explicitly says it loud -- cannot find the codec.

am I alone in this?? or anybody else facing the problem?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

turn off the selinux, then try again.
selinux blocked the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It was solved by changing the Output under "video settings" in preferences of VLC to "X11" from "Automatic".. Save and restart VLC.

Seems obvious but the reason it takes so long to find this problem is because typically when VLC is installed the problem doesn't exist! The problem seems to appear some time later with some update of sorts so since no preferences have been changed by the user, there seems no sense checking there.

Hope it helps.